# Snowflake - Not able to set warehousename using snowsql config file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to connect with snowsql and in cli I am able to manually set warehousename, dbname & schema name. But when i try to put the details in config file in connection property, it is not setting that up in cli. Below are the details in my config file  -

```
[connections.my_conc_dev]

accountname = xxxxxxxxxx

username = xxxxxxxxxx

warehousename = LOAD_WH

dbname = UDHDEV

authenticator = ExternalBrowser
```

I am using below command to connect to snowsql -
*`snowsql -c my_conc_dev`*

It allows me to logged with account and username but not setting up warehouse, db and schema.

xxxxxxxxxxx#(no warehouse)@(no database).(no schema)

Comment: Your config file content and your snowsql call looks good.

This is the kind of behaviour wich happen when an user doesn't have permissions on a given database / schema / warehouse. But you say you are able to set them once connected with USE ?

Comment: Does the user have a default role associated with them? What happens if you add rolename to the config file (for a role with permissions on the objects you want to use)?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with my version of snowsql and I think some of those property names are not quite right. Try this instead:

```
[connections.my_conc_dev]
accountname = xxxxxxxxxx
username = xxxxxxxxxx
warehouse = LOAD_WH
database = UDHDEV
authenticator = ExternalBrowser
```

The documentation says to use `warehousename` and `dbname` but I think it's supposed to be `warehouse` and `database`?

Might be an issue with the doc / older versions of snowsql might use different property names...